# gpiozero import resets pullup

Tags: gpio, python, gpiozero

In order to use a GPIO connected button as a power off switch I have set a pullup for pin 23 in a dtb overlay (following http://blog.gegg.us/2017/01/setting-up-a-gpio-button-keyboard-on-a-raspberry-pi/ and https://github.com/fivdi/onoff/wiki/Enabling-Pullup-and-Pulldown-Resistors-on-The-Raspberry-Pi).

Now in python, when I `import gpiozero` the pin seems to be "reset" and the pullup drops. I don't intend to use pin 23 at all in python. How can I tell gpiozero to leave it alone? Actually i would have assumed the individual pins to only be configured when first used with gpiozero.

Comment: Do you mean GPIO23 on pin 16? See https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: I do not see this behaviour.  Can you include a small script which demonstrates the behaviour?

Comment: @joan yes i'll try this again with a simpler pyhton script. there might have been something else interfering.

Comment: @joan indeed i can't reproduce this with a short script. i also currently can't run the original code since i blew the adafuit motor hat that is usually connected. i'll report back when i have rechecked.

Answer (score 1):

After more testing I found out that there was still active code trying to access GPIO23. As GPIO23 is in use by the kernel, the declaration `btn23 = Button(pin=23, pull_up=True)` fails with `RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection`, which apparently was silently caught in a try/except block.

When an exception is thrown while declaring a `Button`, the `cleanup` routine is called and this is where the pullup gets reset. Since there is no way of querying the pullup state of a GPIO on the raspberry pi hardware (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/76568/103352) it can't be reset to its previous (pulled up) state and hence becomes floating.

I don't think gpiozero can handle this any better than it currently does.

Comment: That sounds like a bug.  It probably shouldn't be tidying up a resource it is not using.